# c# longest common words sample

Tags: c#, algorithm, string, pattern-matching

i am looking for a longest common words c#  implementation. Most of the samples i have came across are comparing character by character.

in otherwords,

```
string1 = access
string2 = advised
```

should return null output from the function

any sample codes?

Comment: Giving an example where the output is nothing is not a very helpful example. Can you give us an example of the algorithm working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by word you mean these letter things, seperated from the others by punktuation, try this:

```
private String longestCommonWord(String s1, String s2)
    {
        String[] seperators = new String[] { " ", ",", ".", "!", "?", ";" };
        var result = from w1 in s1.Split(seperators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                     where (from w2 in s2.Split(seperators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                            where w2 == w1
                            select w2).Count() > 0
                     orderby w1.Length descending
                     select w1;
        if (result.Count() > 0)
        {
            return result.First();
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This probably is not the most elegant way to do it, but it works for me. =)

Comment: Hi Jens, thanks for u r message. this linq query returns a one word.

what i was expecting something like this

string1 = "You are advised to grant access to these settings "
string2 = "these settings "

longestCommonWord(string1 , string2 )

should return "these settings "

Comment: there is algorithm called "Longest common substring problem. " which solves this, but its problem is, it is comparing character by character, 

in my previous example i have mentioned two different words 
string1 = access
string2 = advised 

this function should return nothing because it's two different words, but "Longest common substring problem" algorithm gives "a" which is not what i excpet

Comment: In this case, you have a "Longest common substring problem". If you call your words characters, maybe the algorythm can be modified to work an words instead? E.g. with A="You" B="are" C="adviced" D="access" E="these" F="Settings" your string1 equals ABCDEF, string2 equals EF, and you have reduced your problem to the one already solved.

Comment: I tested the strings "CCCCGTCGGGATAACGGACGACTAACCGGACTGGAGATGATGCATGCTTCCCGCA" and "GCATGCGGCGGTGCGGCATCCGGCTTAATTCCTGTTCAAACCGGATCGCGAAACT", it returned null. Why?

Comment: @Love: The method above returns the longest common word, not the longest common substring. In the eyes of this algorithm, your input consists of two string, each containing one word and since the words are not equal, null is the correct output.

Answer (score 2):

I think this problem is usually referred to as the [Longest common substring problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem). The Wikipedia article contains pseudocode, and C# implementations can be found on the Web.

Comment: but its problem is, it is comparing character by character, in my previous example i have mentioned two different words 

string1 = access string2 = advised 

in this case it returns "a" which is not what i want. it should return nothing because it is two different words.

Answer (score 1):

Turning the algorithm which computes LCS of arrays of characters into one that does it to arrays of anything else -- like, say, an array of words -- is usually pretty straightforward. Have you tried that?

If you need some hints, here's an article I wrote a couple years ago on how to implement Longest Common Subsequence on an array of words in JScript. You should be able to adapt it to C# without too much difficulty.

http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2004/07/21/189974.aspx

Comment: --@Eric, I haven't tried the code. But I just worry if the string is too long and use the method recursively, the system will throw stackoverflow exception. For my case, the string has 20000 chars. I had the problem before.

Answer (score 1):

Finding differences in strings is called the Longest Common Subsequence problem. The following is a generic solution to the LCS problem, written in C#:

```
static int[,] GetLCSDifferenceMatrix<T>(
    Collection<T> baseline,
    Collection<T> revision)
{
    int[,] matrix = new int[baseline.Count + 1, revision.Count + 1];

    for (int baselineIndex = 0; baselineIndex < baseline.Count; baselineIndex++)
    {
        for (int revisionIndex = 0; revisionIndex < revision.Count; revisionIndex++)
        {
            if (baseline[baselineIndex].Equals(revision[revisionIndex]))
            {
                matrix[baselineIndex + 1, revisionIndex + 1] =
                    matrix[baselineIndex, revisionIndex] + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                int possibilityOne = matrix[baselineIndex + 1, revisionIndex];
                int possibilityTwo = matrix[baselineIndex, revisionIndex + 1];

                matrix[baselineIndex + 1, revisionIndex + 1] =
                    Math.Max(possibilityOne, possibilityTwo);
            }
        }
    }

    return matrix;
}
```

This code gives you a "difference" matrix, which can then be used to construct the difference from the two inputs. For unit tests and example usage, see http://sethflowers.com/2012/01/18/basic-diff-with-a-generic-solution-to-the-longest-common-subsequence-problem.html.